# Counting different types of nodes in a Binary Search Tree

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, binary-tree

I am trying to write a recursive function that counts different types of nodes:

- number of nodes with zero children
- number of nodes with one child
- number of nodes with two children

  ```
  def _node_counts_aux(self,node):

      zero = 0
      one = 0
      two = 0

      if node is not None:     
          #print("==========")
          #print(node)
          #print(node._left)
          #print(node._right)
          #print()

          # Two children case
          if node._left is not None and node._right is not None:
              #print("Two")
              two = self._node_counts_aux(node._left)[2] + self._node_counts_aux(node._right)[2] + 1

          # One child case
          elif node._left is None and node._right is not None:
              #print("One")
              one = self._node_counts_aux(node._right)[1] + 1

          elif node._right is None and node._left is not None:
              #print("One")
              one = self._node_counts_aux(node._left)[1] + 1

          # Zero children case
          elif node._left is None and node._right is None:
              #print("Zero")
              zero = self._node_counts_aux(node._left)[0] + self._node_counts_aux(node._right)[0] + 1

      return zero, one, two
  ```

I am confident that the `if` statement structure covers all cases, but when I run my program using this bst [image],               I get this result:

```
Zero children: 0
One child:     0
Two children:  4
```

I have tested my program using print statements and I have determined that there is a problem with my recursive calls. The problem is however, everything (to my knowledge) is correct. Can someone point out my error(s)? Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is `_node_counts_aux()`?

Comment: @avim the code posted is _node_counts_aux()

Comment: Please edit so we can see that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function actually returns the number of subsequent full nodes. You should keep the counters information for each call.

```
def _node_counts_aux(self,node):
    # 'n[i]' is the total number of nodes with 'i' sons
    n = [0,0,0]
    sons = 0

    #one call for left 
    if node._left:
        n = [sum(x) for x in zip(n, self._node_counts_aux(node._left))]
        sons += 1

    #one call for right 
    if node._right:
        n = [sum(x) for x in zip(n, self._node_counts_aux(node._right))]
        sons += 1

    #count this node in the relevant counter 
    n[sons] += 1

    return n
```

Better (code reuse):

```
def _node_counts_aux(self,node):
    # 'n[i]' is the total number of nodes with 'i' sons
    n = [0,0,0]
    sons = 0

    for son_node in [node._left, node._right]:
        if son_node:
            n = [sum(x) for x in zip(n, self._node_counts_aux(son_node))]
            sons += 1

    #count this node in the relevant counter 
    n[sons] += 1

    return n
```

Comment: i should say that this problem is homework, so i mustreturn zero one and two

Comment: It is fine. You can call it exactly as you wanted: `zero,one,two = obj._node_counts_aux(node)`